# Exportación de un datagridview a excel C# Visual Studio 2017/2019

Tags: c#

Estuve leyendo diferentes formas de hacerlo y encontré esta manera: Probé de diferentes formas pero en todas me marca error al momento de crear el documento de `excel`. Ya activé las referencias de `microsoft exce`l 16.0 y no me funciona e incluso he probado usar el using `microsoft.Office` etc... pero igualmente no funciona. Alguien podría explicarme o enseñarme como se hace? :(

```
        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();

        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
           PRIMER ERROR EN DONDE DICE WORBOOK Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
            aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
           SEGUNDO ERROR EN WORBOOKS libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
             hoja_trabajo  =              (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                   TERCER ERROR EN CELLS hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                ERROR EN XLFORMART Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            libros_trabajo.Close(true);
            ERROR EN QUIT aplicacion.Quit();
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es importante que digas que errores recibis. Ponelo en la pregunta usando el boton [edit]

Comment: Qué error te marca?

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras fijate que para cada caso el error similar: microsofot.interop.office etc.. no contiene una definición para worbooks, cells, quit XLFormat

Comment: Al inicio del archivo yo tengo dos líneas que hacen referencia a Excel: 'using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;', es lo único que se me ocurre que podría faltarte.

Comment: tambien ya probe y no sigue marcando los 5 errores